# ¿Recibir JSON en método get?

Tags: nodejs, passport, get

En la autenticación local con passport deseo recibir distintos tipos de respuesta según sea el caso, tengo el siguiente código:

```
// Login user
router.get('/login', (req, res)=>{
    res.send({message:'Usted debe iniciar sesion con su email y su clave'});
});

//Funciones para la autenticacion con passport-local
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email'
}, (username, password, done) => {
    User.findOne({'email': username }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!user) {
            console.log('Usuario incorrecto.');
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Usuario incorrecto.' });
        }
        if (user.password != md5(password)) {
        ///////////////////////////////////
        // Aumenta el atributo try del esquema si la password es incorrecta
        user.try++;
        if (user.try < 5) {

            var update = {
                name: user.name,
                lastName: user.lastName,
                email: user.email,
                password: user.password,
                registerForm: user.registerForm,
                birthDate: user.birthDate,
                try: user.try,
                active: true
            };

            User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, update, (err, TaskUpdated) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(500).send({ error: `Error al actualizar. Error ${err}` });
                }
            });
        } else {
            var update = {
                name: user.name,
                lastName: user.lastName,
                email: user.email,
                password: user.password,
                registerForm: user.registerForm,
                birthDate: user.birthDate,
                try: user.try,
                active: false
            };

            User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, update, (err, TaskUpdated) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(500).send({ error: `Error al actualizar. Error ${err}` });
                }
            });

            if (!user.active) {
                console.log('Tu usuario ha sido bloqueado temporalmente');
            }
        }
        ///////////////////////////////////


        }
            if (user.try < 5) {
                console.log(`Se accedió correctamente`);
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                console.log(`Amigo tienes ${user.try} intentos de login fallidos`);
                //return done(null, false, { message: 'Ha superado el limite de intentos' });           
            }

            return done(null, false, { message: 'Clave incorrecta.' });

    });
}));
```

Deseo poder devolver una respuesta si se introdujo mal la contraseña, si el máximo de intentos permitidos se ha alcanzado (5 intentos), etc.

Pero si envío las respuestas directamente desde la función de passport estas no llegan, alguien sabe como puedo hacer para enviar las respuestas que deseo? O hacerlas llegar al método get?

Answer (score 1):

Passport maneja tres tipos de respuesta:

1. Error interno: (por ejemplo de conexión), hay que llamar a `done(err)`
2. Fallo al loguearse (contraseña es incorrecta, usuario bloqueado o no existe), hay que llamar a `done(null, false, {error: <MENSAJE DE ERROR>})`
3. Todo salió bien, hay que llamar a `done(null, user)`

Dentro de la función que estás declarando no tienes acceso a `req` ni `res`. Sólo puedes llamar a `done` que equivale a llamar a `next` dentro de cualquier middleware.

En tu caso, donde pones

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, update, (err, TaskUpdated) => {
    if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({
            error: `Error al actualizar. Error ${err}`
        });
    }
});
```

Debiera ser

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, update, (err, TaskUpdated) => {
    if (err) {
        return done(err);
    }
});
```

Ahora bien, en este caso el update puede haber sido exitoso, pero si entró en ese bucle es porque el password era incorrecto, de manera que en vez de continuar el flujo, se debe retornar una respuesta del tipo 2.

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, update, (err, TaskUpdated) => {
    if (err) {
        return done(err);
    }
    return done(null, false, {error: 'contraseña incorrecta'});
});
```

Pero esta función es asíncrona y más abajo el flujo siguió corriendo, de manera que puedes llegar al final de la función y gatillar:

```
return done(null, false, {
        message: 'Clave incorrecta.'
    });
```

Cuando más arriba el update también querría llamar a `done`.

Yo organizaría el flujo como sigue:

- Si ocurre un error interno, tiras `done(err)`.
- Si el usuario no existe, `done(null, false, {error: 'Usuario no existe'}`
- Si el usuario está inactivo `done(null, false, {error: 'Usuario inactivo por exceso de intentos'}`
- Si el password calza, `done(null, user)`
- Si no ocurrió nada de lo anterior, significa que el password no calza, por lo que procedes a actualizar los intentos, actualizar el usuario y luego responde.

  ```
  if (err) {
      return done(err);
  }
  if (!user) {
      console.log('Usuario incorrecto.');
      return done(null, false, {
          message: 'Usuario incorrecto.'
      });
  }
  if (!user.active) {
      console.log(`Amigo tienes ${user.try} intentos de login fallidos`);
      return done(null, false, {
          message: 'Ha superado el limite de intentos'
      });
  }
  if (user.password === md5(password)) {
      console.log(`Se accedió correctamente`);
      return done(null, user);
  }

  // Si llegamos acá es porque la contraseña es incorrecta
  // Aumenta el atributo try del esquema si la password es incorrecta
  user.try++;
  var update = {
      name: user.name,
      lastName: user.lastName,
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password,
      registerForm: user.registerForm,
      birthDate: user.birthDate,
      try: user.try,
      active: (user.try < 5)
  };

  return User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, update, (err2, TaskUpdated) => {
      if (err2) {
          return done(err2);
      }
      return done(null, false, {
          message: 'Clave incorrecta.'
      });

  });
  ```

Esto lo usarías de manera que al hacer `POST` a la ruta `/login` llame al middleware `passport.authenticate` pasándole las rutas donde quieres que se envíe al usuario dependiendo del resultado:

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
  successRedirect: '/logueado',
  failureRedirect: '/login',
  failureFlash: true
});
```

De manera que si algo falla, te va a mandar a `router.get(/login...`.

Cuando se invoque `next` el middleware o ruta siguiente podrá acceder al usuario via `req.user`, mientras que el error que pasas como tercer parámetro a `done` lo puedes leer de `req.flash('error')`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación! Aunque sigo teniendo una duda, ¿Cómo podría enviar los mensaje de respuesta? Porque no los veo ni en la terminal ni en la herramienta que utilizo para probar las peticiones (postman)?

Comment: Añadí un párrafo explicando cómo se usa el middleware en una ruta POST. El mensaje de error estaría en `req.flash('error')` y la info del usuario en `req.session.user`

Comment: Corregí algo: por defecto el usuario autenticado debiera quedar en `req.user`